# Angular 6 with SSR and i18n getting error "You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped"

Tags: angular, server-side-rendering, angular-universal, angular-webpack

ERROR: https://github.com/mixalistzikas/angular-ssr-i18n

```
Run `npm run build:all`. Navigate to `http://localhost:4201/`.
```

I'm trying to make server side rendering with i18n. I have already done this with angular <=5 but now with angular CLI 6, I'm getting trouble.

I'm running "npm run build:all" and everyting finish without any error...

browser files.... DONE
server files.... DONE
webpack..... DONE

But when I'm trying to open the site at "listening on http://localhost:4201" I'm always get the following error

```
Error: You must pass in a NgModule or NgModuleFactory to be bootstrapped
```

Thank you.... If you need any other file tell me to upload it

package.json

```
{
"name": "frontend-admin",
"version": "0.0.0",
"scripts": {
  "ng": "ng",
  "start": "ng serve",
  "build": "ng build",
  "test": "ng test",
  "lint": "ng lint",
  "e2e": "ng e2e",
  "build:all": "node scripts/build.js && node scripts/build.js --server=true && webpack --mode production && node ./dist/server.js",
  "build:web": "node scripts/build.js",
  "build:server": "node scripts/build.js --server=true",
  "build:webpack": "webpack --mode production",
  "start:server": "node ./dist/server.js",
  "build-i18n": "for lang in en el; do ng build --output-path=dist/$lang --aot --prod --i18n-file=src/i18n/messages.$lang.xlf --i18n-format=xlf --i18n-locale $lang --base-href /$lang/; done"
},
"private": true,
"dependencies": {
  "@agm/core": "^1.0.0-beta.3",
  "@angular/animations": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/common": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/compiler": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/core": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/forms": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/http": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/platform-server": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/router": "^6.0.7",
  "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^2.2.0",
  "@ng-bootstrap/schematics": "^2.0.0-alpha.1",
  "@nguniversal/express-engine": "^6.0.0",
  "@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader": "^6.0.0",
  "@ngxs/devtools-plugin": "^3.1.3",
  "@ngxs/logger-plugin": "^3.1.3",
  "@ngxs/store": "^3.1.3",
  "bootstrap": "^4.1.1",
  "core-js": "^2.5.7",
  "moment": "^2.22.2",
  "ngx-dropzone-wrapper": "^6.1.0",
  "ngx-moment": "^3.1.0",
  "rxjs": "^6.2.0",
  "ts-loader": "^4.4.2",
  "zone.js": "^0.8.26"
},
"devDependencies": {
  "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.6.8",
  "@angular/cli": "~6.0.8",
  "@angular/compiler-cli": "^6.0.7",
  "@angular/language-service": "^6.0.7",
  "@types/googlemaps": "^3.30.11",
  "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
  "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
  "@types/node": "^10.1.4",
  "codelyzer": "~4.3.0",
  "jasmine-core": "~3.1.0",
  "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
  "karma": "^2.0.4",
  "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
  "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
  "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
  "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.2.0",
  "protractor": "~5.3.2",
  "ts-node": "^6.1.2",
  "tslint": "^5.10.0",
  "typescript": "~2.7.2",
  "webpack-cli": "^3.0.8",
  "webpack-node-externals": "^1.7.2"
}
}
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
"compileOnSave": false,
"compilerOptions": {
  "baseUrl": "./",
  "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
  "sourceMap": true,
  "declaration": false,
  "moduleResolution": "node",
  "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
  "experimentalDecorators": true,
  "target": "es5",
  "typeRoots": [
     "node_modules/@types"
  ],
  "lib": [
     "es2017",
     "dom"
  ],
  "paths": {
     "_components/*": [
        "src/app/core/components/*"
     ],
     "_directives/*": [
        "src/app/core/directives/*"
     ],
     "_services/*": [
        "src/app/core/services/*"
     ],
     "_pipes/*": [
        "src/app/core/pipes/*"
     ],
     "_layouts/*": [
        "src/app/core/layouts/*"
     ],
     "_shared/*": [
        "src/app/core/shared/*"
     ],
     "_layouts/*": [
        "src/app/core/layouts/*"
     ],
     "_validators/*": [
        "src/app/core/validators/*"
     ],
     "_guards/*": [
        "src/app/core/guards/*"
     ]
  }
 }
}
```

src/tsconfig.app.json

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
    "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
    "module": "es2015",
    "types": []
},
"exclude": [
    "src/test.ts",
    "**/*.spec.ts"
]
}
```

src/tsconfig.server.json

```
{
"extends": "../tsconfig.json",
"compilerOptions": {
  "outDir": "../out-tsc/app",
  "module": "commonjs",
  "types": []
},
"exclude": [
  "test.ts",
  "**/*.spec.ts"
],
"angularCompilerOptions": {
   "entryModule": "app/app.server.module#AppServerModule"
}
}
```

src/main.server.ts

```
export { AppServerModule } from './app/app.server.module';
```

angular.json

```
 {
 "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
 "version": 1,
 "newProjectRoot": "projects",
 "projects": {
  "frontend-admin": {
     "root": "",
     "sourceRoot": "src",
     "projectType": "application",
     "prefix": "app",
     "schematics": {},
     "architect": {
        "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
           "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/browser",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "assets": [
                 "src/favicon.ico",
                 "src/assets"
              ],
              "styles": [
                 "src/styles.scss",
                 "src/assets/css/variables.scss",
                 "src/assets/font/AvertaStd/stylesheet.css",
                 "src/assets/css/layout.scss",
                 {
                    "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
                 }
              ],
              "scripts": []
           },
           "configurations": {
              "production": {
                 "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                       "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                 ],
                 "optimization": true,
                 "outputHashing": "all",
                 "sourceMap": false,
                 "extractCss": true,
                 "namedChunks": false,
                 "aot": true,
                 "extractLicenses": true,
                 "vendorChunk": false,
                 "buildOptimizer": true
              }
           }
        },
        "serve": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
           "options": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-admin:build"
           },
           "configurations": {
              "production": {
                 "browserTarget": "frontend-admin:build:production"
              }
           }
        },
        "server": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:server",
           "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/app/server",
              "main": "src/main.server.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json"
           },
           "configurations": {
              "production": {
                 "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                       "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
           "options": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-admin:build"
           }
        },
        "test": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
           "options": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
              "styles": [
                 "styles.scss"
              ],
              "scripts": [],
              "assets": [
                 "src/favicon.ico",
                 "src/assets"
              ]
           }
        },
        "lint": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
           "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                 "src/tsconfig.app.json",
                 "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                 "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
           }
        }
     }
   },
   "frontend-admin-server": {

     "root": "",
     "sourceRoot": "src",
     "projectType": "application",
     "prefix": "dt",
     "schematics": {},
     "architect": {
        "build": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
           "options": {
              "outputPath": "dist/server",
              "index": "src/index.html",
              "main": "src/main.server.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.json",
              "assets": [],
              "styles": [],
              "scripts": []
           },
           "configurations": {
              "production": {
                 "fileReplacements": [
                    {
                       "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                       "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                    }
                 ],
                 "optimization": true,
                 "outputHashing": "all",
                 "sourceMap": false,
                 "extractCss": true,
                 "namedChunks": false,
                 "aot": true,
                 "extractLicenses": true,
                 "vendorChunk": false,
                 "buildOptimizer": true
              }
           }
        },
        "serve": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
           "options": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-admin-server:build"
           },
           "configurations": {
              "production": {
                 "browserTarget": "frontend-admin-server:build:production"
              }
           }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
           "options": {
              "browserTarget": "frontend-admin-server:build"
           }
        },
        "test": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
           "options": {
              "main": "src/test.ts",
              "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
              "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.server.spec.json",
              "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
              "styles": [
                 "styles.scss"
              ],
              "scripts": [],
              "assets": [
                 "src/favicon.ico",
                 "src/assets"
              ]
           }
        },
        "lint": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
           "options": {
              "tsConfig": [
                 "src/tsconfig.server.json",
                 "src/tsconfig.server.spec.json"
              ],
              "exclude": [
                 "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
           }
        }
     }
   },
   "frontend-admin-e2e": {
     "root": "e2e/",
     "projectType": "application",
     "architect": {
        "e2e": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
           "options": {
              "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
              "devServerTarget": "frontend-admin:serve"
           }
        },
        "lint": {
           "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
           "options": {
              "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
              "exclude": [
                 "**/node_modules/**"
              ]
           }
        }
     }
  }
},
"defaultProject": "frontend-admin",
"schematics": {
  "@schematics/angular:component": {
     "styleext": "scss"
  }
}
}
```

scripts/build.js

```
const execSync = require('child_process').execSync;
const path = require('path');
const project = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'project.json'));
const args = require('yargs').argv;

const locales = Object.keys(project.locales);

const baseCommand = args.server === 'true' ? project.server.command : 
project.client.command;
const folder = args.server === 'true' ? project.server.output : 
project.client.output;

function buildCommand(command, locale, output, needFile) {
 command += ` --output-path dist/${output}/${locale.toLowerCase()} --deploy-url /${locale.toLowerCase()}/ --base-href /${locale.toLowerCase()}/ --i18n-locale=${locale}`;
if (needFile) {
  command += ` --i18n- =file=src/i18n/messages.${locale.toLowerCase()}.xlf --i18n-format=xlf`;
   }
 console.log(command);
   return command;
}

for (let i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
   console.info(`Building for locale ${locales[i]}...`);
   execSync(buildCommand(baseCommand, locales[i], folder, 
project.locales[locales[i]]), { cwd: process.cwd(), stdio: [0, 1, 2] });
   console.info();
}

process.exit(0);
```

webpack.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const project = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'project.json'));
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');
const webpack = require('webpack');

const locales = Object.keys(project.locales);

const config = {
entry: {
  server: './server.ts'
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  alias: {}
},
target: 'node',
externals: [nodeExternals({
  whitelist: [
  ]
})],
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
  rules: [{
     test: /\.ts$/,
     loader: 'ts-loader'
  }]
},
plugins: [
  // ...
  new webpack.DefinePlugin({
     'process.env.BROWSER': JSON.stringify(true),
     'window': JSON.stringify(true)
  }),
  // ...
]
};

 for (let i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
   config.resolve.alias[`main.server.${locales[i].toLowerCase()}`] = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'server', locales[i].toLowerCase(), 'main.js')
}

module.exports = config;
```

webpack.server.config.js

```
const path = require('path');
const project = require(path.join(process.cwd(), 'project.json'));
var nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

const locales = Object.keys(project.locales);

const config = {
entry: {
  server: './server.ts'
},
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.ts', '.js'],
  alias: {}
},
target: 'node',
externals: [nodeExternals()],
output: {
  path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
  filename: '[name].js'
},
module: {
  rules: [{
     test: /\.ts$/,
     loader: 'ts-loader'
  }]
}
};

for (let i = 0; i < locales.length; i++) {
config.resolve.alias[`main.server.${locales[i].toLowerCase()}`] = path.join(__dirname, 'dist', 'server', locales[i].toLowerCase(), 'main.js')
}

module.exports = config;
```

project.json

```
{
"locales": {
  "en": true,
  "el": true
},
"client": {
  "command": "ng build frontend-admin --prod --build-optimizer",
  "output": "browser"
},
"server": {
  "command": "ng build frontend-admin-server --aot",
  "output": "server"
}
}
```

src/app/app.server.module.ts

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ServerModule } from '@angular/platform-server';
import { ModuleMapLoaderModule } from '@nguniversal/module-map-ngfactory-loader';

import { AppModule } from './app.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
  AppModule,
  ServerModule,
  ModuleMapLoaderModule
],
providers: [
// Add universal-only providers here
],
bootstrap: [ AppComponent ],
})
export class AppServerModule {
constructor() {
  //const platform = isPlatformBrowser(platformId) ? 'in the browser' : 'on the server';
  console.log(`11111111111111111111111111111`);
}
}
```

Comment: Can you also include `project.json`? We're interested in `project.server.command` and `project.client.command` options

Comment: check again.. just include it

Comment: any idea @yurzui ?

Comment: https://github.com/mixalistzikas/angular-ssr-i18n (completed error example)

Comment: You incorrectly build server bundle

Comment: Could you please suggest a solution?

Comment: You created two entry points for server configuration in angular.json: `frontend-admin:server` and `frontend-admin-server:build`

Comment: Server build should use `@angular-devkit/build-angular:server` while you're using `@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser`

Comment: I change this command and now I'm getting this error during compile: Schema validation failed with the following errors:
  Data path "" should NOT have additional properties(index).

Comment: I remove every addition properties like index... Now I'm getting "Unknow option --aot". Maybe from this line "ng build ssri18nserver --aot". Any suggestion

Comment: That's because you should appropriate scheme for server configuration. Look at universal starter https://github.com/angular/universal-starter/blob/7242a36d246b028fcff09e2ad3551c6e829b63a9/angular.json#L108-L126 They have additional section inside current project and build it through `ng run ng-universal-demo:server:production` where `ng-universal-demo` is name of project and `server` is option in architect section for this project. In your case this command could look like `ng run frontend-admin:server:production`

Comment: Main your problem is that your main.js bundle emitted from server build doesn't have AppComponentNgFactory exported. I see all the errors you wrote above in comments. But i also can't tell exactly why we can't build universal with additional `build` section. angular.json configuration file became like a grunt with a lot of options)

Comment: Related issue here https://github.com/angular/devkit/issues/986

Comment: :-( I will try to find a solution.... Strange errors

Comment: You created second project called `frontend-admin-server` for server configuration but seems you should be using the same `frontend-admin` project but only `architect.server` configuration. And `ng run frontend-admin:server:production` will give you correct output with generated AppComponentNgFactory but i'm unsure about all additional parameters.

Comment: You can check again: https://github.com/mixalistzikas/angular-ssr-i18n .

Now the error is as we say previously is: Unknown option: '--deployUrl'

Comment: Yeah, i created similar reproduction locally

Comment: I send a bug request at angular (github)

Comment: FYI: https://github.com/enten/angular-universal/blob/master/angular.json (from another example - not mine)

Comment: FYI: check the repo.... i fix it